# Banner isn't showing up in IE7 and IE8

Tags: image, internet-explorer

Here's the site: http://soundlabrecordingstudio.com/

I have the right filepath, and the image is RGB. Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE9 give me wrong color... near the red.

Comment: To avoid problem and solution, just save it in PNG in paint and it will do the job.

Comment: Your welcome, just be sure to accept my answer below to confirm it so others will be able to see the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in OP's comment, saved in PNG solved the problem.

My opinion : The JPEG encoding was probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your source code. Just after the `<body>` tag, you wrote  `<div id='container'­->` instead of `<div id='container'>` (no extra-dash). FF is great, he corrects automatically. IE panics.

Comment: Thanks for opening up a whole new world of debugging, lol. The dash only shows up when I look at the source code in IE. Really though, thank you---wouldn't have spotted that otherwise.