# How to apply SVG so that it works in IE background image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

My problem is similar to issue discussion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556731/css-background-image-not-loading-in-ie9). The background images works in all other browser including IE10 but doesn't work below IE10. I have created a background image in SVG format for IE10 below after reading in that post. Now, I don't know how to apply this to my CSS.

**CSS**

```
.bg-secondary { 
        background: url(../img/design/bg-secondary.jpg) no-repeat top center; 
      -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
      -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
      -o-background-size: 100% auto;
      background-size: 100% auto;
      min-height: 605px;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/design/bg-secondary.svg', sizingMethod='scale');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a css technique with multiple backgrounds here:

```
  .bg-secondary {
  background-image: url(fallback.png);
  background-image: url(image.svg), none;
  -----
  -----  
  }
```

> This works because it just so happens that the browser support for SVG
>   and multiple-backgrounds is very similar. If multiple backgrounds is
>   supported, the browser will use the second declaration (with SVG),
>   otherwise fall back to the first declaration (with PNG).

**Updated:**

```
<svg width="--" height="--">
  <image xlink:href="your.svg" src="svg.png" width="--" height="--" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @NavneilNaicker Can you try using the updated format? it is not applying as background-image but still to check as I don't have an IE browser at the moment.

Comment: Most browsers don't allow img elements and css (background)images to load additional external resources for security reasons. My guess is that IE blocks such references too, that means that in the example `<svg><image /></svg>` it will not show the image inside (unless possibly it was encoded as a data uri). You can replace the <image/> with e.g a <circle/> to test that the svg itself loads correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try this if it helps...

```
<svg  height="--px" width="--px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                                            <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="imagefilehere.svg"/>
                                    </svg>
```